# How to disable a button in android in response if the edit text changed?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an android application, with 3 buttons. The first button is always enabled but the others are disabled. So if the first button git the right response the other 2 buttons will be enabled , else it will stay disabled. This works good.

Now if the first button git the right response, but the user changed the edit text again i need a way to make the 2 other buttons be disabled again.

This what i have done :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Askbutton);
     btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Addbutton);
    btn1.setEnabled(false);
    btn2.setEnabled(false);}

public void SearchClickHandler(View view){

DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this );

       if (view.getId() == R.id.Searchbutton) {
         EditText BookN = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Bookname);
         String Book_n = BookN.getText().toString() ;
        TextView resultT =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultLable);
            Books book = db.findbook(Book_n);

                      if(book != null ) {
                btn1.setEnabled(true);
                btn2.setEnabled(true);

                resultT.setText(Book_n + " is avaliable ");

            if(BookN.isInEditMode()) {
        btn1.setEnabled(false);
        btn2.setEnabled(false);
                }

             } else {
                 resultT.setText("We are sorry,  "+ Book_n + "  is not avaliable");
                }
       }
      }
```

Comment: adding listner to edittext will work,based on what kind of check you are making on edittext you can choose listner

Comment: i want to check if the user after git the right response and the other  2 buttons enabled, to check if the he changed the edittext for a new search the other buttons will disabled as the first launch. I will try the listener to see if it works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must use `addTextChangedListener()` method.

```
BookN = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Bookname);
BookN.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        //use s.length() for enable and disable Button
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, it may help u

```
BookN.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
            return false;
            btn1.setEnabled(false);
            btn2.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

implement `TextWatcher` for `EditText`
Here is the [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 BookN .addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {   
   }   
   @Override
 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
int after) {    
 }
   @Override
     public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
     String st=BookN.getText().toString();
       btn1.setEnabled(false);
        btn2.setEnabled(false);
    }
    }
  });
```